# How to hide system fields (oro platform 2.1.0 & symfony 2.8)

Tags: php, symfony, field, hide

I am using Oro Platform and AccountBundle (OroCRM).

I want to remove (hide) social fields, and customize the address for my location (hide unnecessary fields). How can I do this? What to edit in code? Custom fields (created in ui) can be freely edited. The problem is with system fields.

Can I edit views (twig.html)? Is there another way? What is good practice?

UserBundle/Form/Type/UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

use Oro\Bundle\FormBundle\Form\Type\OroBirthdayType;
use Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityFacade;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\EventListener\UserSubscriber;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Provider\PasswordFieldOptionsProvider;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var SecurityContextInterface */
    protected $security;

    /** @var SecurityFacade */
    protected $securityFacade;

    /** @var bool */
    protected $isMyProfilePage;

    /** @var PasswordFieldOptionsProvider */
    protected $optionsProvider;

    /**
     * @param SecurityContextInterface $security Security context
     * @param SecurityFacade $securityFacade
     * @param Request $request                   Request
     * @param PasswordFieldOptionsProvider $optionsProvider
     */
    public function __construct(
        SecurityContextInterface $security,
        SecurityFacade           $securityFacade,
        Request $request,
        PasswordFieldOptionsProvider $optionsProvider
    ) {
        $this->security          = $security;
        $this->securityFacade    = $securityFacade;

        $this->isMyProfilePage = $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'oro_user_profile_update';
        $this->optionsProvider = $optionsProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->addEntityFields($builder);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addEntityFields(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
    {
        // user fields
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new UserSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory(), $this->security));
        $this->setDefaultUserFields($builder);
        if ($this->securityFacade->isGranted('oro_user_role_view')) {
            $builder->add(
                'roles',
                'entity',
                [
                    'property_path' => 'rolesCollection',
                    'label'         => 'oro.user.roles.label',
                    'class'         => 'OroUserBundle:Role',
                    'property'      => 'label',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                            ->where('r.role <> :anon')
                            ->setParameter('anon', User::ROLE_ANONYMOUS)
                            ->orderBy('r.label');
                    },
                    'multiple'      => true,
                    'expanded'      => true,
                    'required'      => !$this->isMyProfilePage,
                    'read_only'     => $this->isMyProfilePage,
                    'disabled'      => $this->isMyProfilePage,
                    'translatable_options' => false
                ]
            );
        }
        if ($this->securityFacade->isGranted('oro_user_group_view')) {
            $builder->add(
                'groups',
                'entity',
                [
                    'label'     => 'oro.user.groups.label',
                    'class'     => 'OroUserBundle:Group',
                    'property'  => 'name',
                    'multiple'  => true,
                    'expanded'  => true,
                    'required'  => false,
                    'read_only' => $this->isMyProfilePage,
                    'disabled'  => $this->isMyProfilePage,
                    'translatable_options' => false
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->addOrganizationField($builder);
        $builder
            ->add(
                'plainPassword',
                'repeated',
                [
                    'invalid_message' => 'oro.user.message.password_mismatch',
                    'type'           => 'password',
                    'required'       => true,
                    'first_options' => [
                        'label' => 'oro.user.password.label',
                        'tooltip' => $this->optionsProvider->getTooltip(),
                        'attr' => [
                            'data-validation' => $this->optionsProvider->getDataValidationOption()
                        ]
                    ],
                    'second_options' => [
                        'label' => 'oro.user.password_re.label',
                    ],
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'emails',
                'collection',
                [
                    'label'          => 'oro.user.emails.label',
                    'type'           => 'oro_user_email',
                    'allow_add'      => true,
                    'allow_delete'   => true,
                    'by_reference'   => false,
                    'prototype'      => true,
                    'prototype_name' => 'tag__name__'
                ]
            )
            ->add('change_password', ChangePasswordType::NAME)
            ->add('avatar', 'oro_image', ['label' => 'oro.user.avatar.label', 'required' => false]);

        $this->addInviteUserField($builder);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class'           => 'Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User',
                'intention'            => 'user',
                'validation_groups'    => function ($form) {
                    if ($form instanceof FormInterface) {
                        $user = $form->getData();
                    } elseif ($form instanceof FormView) {
                        $user = $form->vars['value'];
                    } else {
                        $user = null;
                    }

                    return $user && $user->getId()
                        ? ['Roles', 'Default']
                        : ['Registration', 'Roles', 'Default'];
                },
                'ownership_disabled'   => $this->isMyProfilePage
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'oro_user_user';
    }

    /**
     * Set user fields
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     */
    protected function setDefaultUserFields(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', 'text', ['label' => 'oro.user.username.label', 'required' => true])
            ->add('email', 'email', ['label' => 'oro.user.email.label', 'required' => true])
            ->add('phone', 'text', ['label' => 'oro.user.phone.label', 'required' => false])
            ->add('namePrefix', 'text', ['label' => 'oro.user.name_prefix.label', 'required' => false])
            ->add('firstName', 'text', ['label' => 'oro.user.first_name.label', 'required' => true])
            ->add('middleName', 'text', ['label' => 'oro.user.middle_name.label', 'required' => false])
            ->add('lastName', 'text', ['label' => 'oro.user.last_name.label', 'required' => true])
            ->add('nameSuffix', 'text', ['label' => 'oro.user.name_suffix.label', 'required' => false])
            ->add('birthday', OroBirthdayType::class, ['label' => 'oro.user.birthday.label', 'required' => false]);
    }

    /**
     * Add Invite user fields
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     */
    protected function addInviteUserField(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'inviteUser',
            'checkbox',
            [
                'label'    => 'oro.user.invite.label',
                'mapped'   => false,
                'required' => false,
                'tooltip'  => 'oro.user.invite.tooltip',
                'data'     => true
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     */
    protected function addOrganizationField(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
    {
        if ($this->securityFacade->isGranted('oro_organization_view')
            && $this->securityFacade->isGranted('oro_business_unit_view')
        ) {
            $builder->add(
                'organizations',
                'oro_organizations_select',
                [
                    'required' => false,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

... /Entity/User.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

    use Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Entity\EmailOrigin;
    use Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Entity\EmailOwnerInterface;
    use Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Model\EmailHolderInterface;
    use Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Metadata\Annotation\Config;
    use Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Metadata\Annotation\ConfigField;
    use Oro\Bundle\ImapBundle\Entity\UserEmailOrigin;
    use Oro\Bundle\ImapBundle\Form\Model\AccountTypeModel;
    use Oro\Bundle\LocaleBundle\Model\FullNameInterface;
    use Oro\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Entity\NotificationEmailInterface;
    use Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Entity\BusinessUnit;
    use Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Entity\Organization;
    use Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Entity\OrganizationInterface;
    use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Model\ExtendUser;
    use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Security\AdvancedApiUserInterface;

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessivePublicCount)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassLength)
     *
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
     * @ORM\Table(name="oro_user", indexes = {
     *      @ORM\Index("user_first_name_last_name_idx", columns = {"first_name", "last_name"})
     * })
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     * @Config(
     *      routeName="oro_user_index",
     *      routeView="oro_user_view",
     *      defaultValues={
     *          "entity"={
     *              "icon"="fa-user"
     *          },
     *          "grouping"={
     *              "groups"={"dictionary"}
     *          },
     *          "dictionary"={
     *              "virtual_fields"={"id"},
     *              "search_fields"={"firstName", "lastName"},
     *              "representation_field"="fullName",
     *              "activity_support"="true"
     *          },
     *          "ownership"={
     *              "owner_type"="BUSINESS_UNIT",
     *              "owner_field_name"="owner",
     *              "owner_column_name"="business_unit_owner_id",
     *              "organization_field_name"="organization",
     *              "organization_column_name"="organization_id"
     *          },
     *          "dataaudit"={"auditable"=true},
     *          "security"={
     *              "type"="ACL",
     *              "group_name"="",
     *              "category"="account_management"
     *          },
     *          "form"={
     *              "form_type"="oro_user_select",
     *              "grid_name"="users-select-grid"
     *          },
     *          "grid"={
     *              "default"="users-grid",
     *              "context"="users-for-context-grid"
     *          },
     *          "tag"={
     *              "enabled"=true
     *          }
     *      }
     * )
     * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("ALL")
     */
    class User extends ExtendUser implements
        EmailOwnerInterface,
        EmailHolderInterface,
        FullNameInterface,
        NotificationEmailInterface,
        OrganizationAwareUserInterface,
        AdvancedApiUserInterface
    {
        const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_USER';
        const ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR = 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR';
        const ROLE_ANONYMOUS = 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY';

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @JMS\Type("integer")
         * @JMS\Expose
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         * @JMS\Type("string")
         * @JMS\Expose
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          },
         *          "importexport"={
         *              "identity"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
        protected $username;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         * @JMS\Type("string")
         * @JMS\Expose
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
        protected $email;

        /**
         * Name prefix
         *
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name_prefix", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         * @JMS\Type("string")
         * @JMS\Expose
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
        protected $namePrefix;

        /**
         * First name
         *
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         * @JMS\Type("string")
         * @JMS\Expose
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
        protected $firstName;

        /**
         * Middle name
         *
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="middle_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         * @JMS\Type("string")
         * @JMS\Expose
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
        protected $middleName;

        /**
         * Last name
         *
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         * @JMS\Type("string")
         * @JMS\Expose
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
        protected $lastName;

        /**
         * Name suffix
         *
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name_suffix", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         * @JMS\Type("string")
         * @JMS\Expose
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
        protected $nameSuffix;

        /**
         * @var Group[]|Collection
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Group")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="oro_user_access_group",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
         * )
         * @ConfigField(
         *      defaultValues={
         *          "dataaudit"={
         *              "auditable"=true
         *          }
         *      }
         * )
         */
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the UserBundle and override the parts you need.
[Symfony docs for bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html).